# View .js files in IE8 in the browser?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Whenever I try to view .js in IE8 by just visiting the .js url, it prompts for a download. how can i view the actual code without downloading it?

Answer (score 4):

Press F12 in IE8

[image: Press F12 in IE8]

select `js` script:

[image: select <code>js</code> script]

Comment: He said he wants to open the .JS URL *directly*, not access the .JS linked from an HTML page. Suppose the file is http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js, can you tell me how IE's Developer Tools will help? As soon as you enter the URL IE will prompt you to download the file.